# How to run aliases under tmux without root privilege

Tags: alias, tmux

Under terminal multiplexer `tmux` I am unable to use alias as a normal user.

```
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

For alias of alias `l` I have to type `ls -CF --color=auto` each time which is not any fun.
But same `l` alias will run under multiplexer `screen` without root privilege.
So how do I use alias as a normal user under `tmux`.

Comment: Copy those aliases to root's `.bashrc`.

Comment: @muru root's `.bashrc` also have those aliases

Comment: What does `shopt expand_aliases` show from inside tmux?

Comment: It shows `on` ..

Answer (score 1):

**Temporary way:**

```
$ tmux
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ l
```

**Permanent way:**
Put `source ~/.bashrc` anywhere on *.bash_profile*.

```
$ tmux
$ l
```